# Spectrum analyzer for .raw 16bit linear files

Tags: qt, spectrum

I have to make a spectrum analyzer for .raw 16-bit linear files.

I had a look at [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimedia-spectrum-example.html) but it works only with .wav files.

Do you know any tutorial/example that can help me create a spectrum analyzer for .raw files?

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: I need a tutorial/hint to help me in making a spectrum analyzer for .raw 16-bit linear files.

Comment: No you don't. You can use the same tutorial as in your question. What you need is a way of reading .raw files and then putting the data you get from there in the same format as used in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WavFile`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimedia-spectrum-app-wavfile-cpp.html) class reads a `.wav` header to obtain the audio format information from the file. It's simple to modify that class to use a fixed format instead.

If you look at the documentation for the [`QAudioInput`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaudioinput.html) class, the first code sample given shows how to set up the `QAudioInput` to read a raw file with a format slightly different from yours. All you need is to adapt the parameters of the `QAudioFormat` instance to match your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with RobbieE in the comments in that what you need is not a different tutorial, but a method to convert RAW files to WAV files. I am also currently working on an audio application in Qt, and the library I use is [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) by Erik de Castro Lopo. It can transfer to and from many, many formats, including RAW to WAV.

If the Qt tutorial requires the sound to be loaded as a QSound (which I assume it does), you will first have to convert the RAW file to a WAV file, save it, and then proceed to load the WAV file.

Comment: If you need some example code, I can pass some of mine along to you. Just send me a message.

Comment: This is not very helpful. `QSound` is a convenience class used to play `wav` files. There's no need to convert anything to a `.wav` files. Qt can read raw files just fine.

Comment: MrMallIronmaker, can you pass me some code exemple please? I still can't figure out how to resolve this problem...